I can’t send matic or mint an nft with my polygon mainnet
I have 48 matic in my wallet that I sent to myself 10 days ago.
Now that matic seems to be stuck on my wallet.
I connected to a mint site (that is 100% legit and trustworthy) and it won’t allow my mint transaction to go through. I connect the wallet and execute the mint function but it fails.
I cleared the cache and reinstalled the polygon network. Still nothing.
So I decided to send the matic to a different wallet and try from a different address but now I can’t even send my matic to my other wallet
In the overview I can see the matic amount but when metamask is trying to execute any type of transaction it shows a balance of 0.00099 MATIC
Wallet address
0x73D153b0421F4fA9b2dacE3E1faa431AA7a303Cb
Here is one of the transaction hashes:
0xa54e122f6ec9a9d1886cbb6cc9bc0a46946f6d38f942bcf5fe2fec4b1cb3db27

share your wallet address and transaction hashes, no one can answer without looking at the wallet.

Ok added the wallet!
